# clang-format removes indents in if condition when there is a line break

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have this function:

```
bool WS::receive(MB *const buffer) const {
    updateLastPackage();
    if ((!lastPackage_.empty()) &&
            (lastPackage_.size() <= buffer->capacity()) &&
            (lastUpdate_.getTime() <= settings_.refreshPeriod)) {
        buffer->clear();
        (*buffer) << lastPackage_;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

After apply clang-format with my style file:

```
bool WS::receive(MB *const buffer) const {
    updateLastPackage();
    if ((!lastPackage_.empty()) &&
    (lastPackage_.size() <= buffer->capacity()) &&
    (lastUpdate_.getTime() <= settings_.refreshPeriod)) {
        buffer->clear();
        (*buffer) << lastPackage_;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can see that clang-format removes indents in if condition when there is a line break. So, how to keep indents unchanged? This also happened with templates.

My style file, based on LLVM:
https://pastebin.com/ZDwZfBud

Comment: It seems to be covered by AlignOperands, but to actually add some indent, you would need to modify ContinuationIndentWidth, which may change other parts of code.

Comment: Did you mean removes indents in `if` condition, instead of function parameters?

Comment: @cigien yes, sorry my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks goes to Yksisarvinen.

Solution:

```
AlignOperands: false
ContinuationIndentWidth: 8
```